# REST Kit 0.10.0 - POST is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I'm using **REST Kit 0.10.0** and I'm unable to do the `RKRequestMethodPOST`.

My database name is **dbo.Patients** and table name is **Patient**.

It contains 3 columns such as `ID,Name,Address`

Here is my code,

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/Patient" delegate:self];
RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class]];
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://175.78.1.4/MyAppTestData/MyAppDataService.svc"];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;
[venueMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"ID",@"Id",@"Name",@"name",@"Address",@"midname",nil];

[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:venueMapping forKeyPath:@"value"];

RKObjectMapping* venueMappingS = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class]];
venueMappingS.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;

[[RKClient sharedClient] setUsername:@"sa"];
[[RKClient sharedClient] setPassword:@"123"];

RKObjectRouter *router = [[RKObjectRouter alloc] init];

[router routeClass:[Venue class] toResourcePath:@"/Patient" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] setMapping:venueMappingS forKeyPath:@"value"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[venueMappingS inverseMapping] forClass:[Venue class]];
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router = router;
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].acceptMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;


Venue* venue = [[Venue alloc] init];
venue.Id = 4;
venue.name = @"User1";
venue.midname =  @"Chicago";

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:venue delegate:self];
```

Currently its shows an error as

> W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:81 Adding mapping error:
>   Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''

Here is my **Venue** class

```
@interface Venue : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *uri;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *midname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *mrn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *gender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *accession;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate   *dob;
@property (nonatomic) int Id;

@end
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] setMapping:venueMappingS forKeyPath:@"value"];
```

change keypath @"venue" to something else because it matches your response mapping keypath.ex:@"reqVenue"

or use this

```
    RKObjectMapping * entitySerializationMapping = [(RKObjectMapping*) [manager.mappingProvider   mappingForKeyPath: @"reqVenue"] inverseMapping];

    [manager.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:entitySerializationMapping
                                                    forClass:[Venue class]];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] 
 postObject:venue
 mapResponseWith:venueMapping 
 delegate:self];
```

Comment: Application crashing " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You must provide a serialization mapping for objects of type 'Venue ' "

Comment: from where i can get the keypath ? is it from WCF service ? or my Xcode code itself ?

Comment: you have to change keypath of your request mapping

Comment: change keypath of req mapping [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] setMapping:venueMappingS forKeyPath:@"reqvalue"];